# Java Merge Sorting Compare and Count

Tags: java, merge

I have been having trouble with figuring this problem out. I've added a count and compare to identify how many times my sort actually does something and I believe that I am doing it incorrectly because it is not matching up to my example.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

/**
 * @param args
 */

// Rearranges the elements of a into sorted order using
// the merge sort algorithm (recursive).
static int compCount;
static int swapCount; 
public  void mergeSort(int[] a, int howMany) {    
    if (a.length >= 2) {
        // split array into two halves
        int[] left  = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length/2);
        int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, a.length/2, a.length);

        // sort the two halves
        mergeSort(left,howMany);
        mergeSort(right, howMany);

        // merge the sorted halves into a sorted whole
        merge(a, left, right);
    }
    swapCount++;
}

// Merges the left/right elements into a sorted result.
// Precondition: left/right are sorted
public static void merge(int[] result, int[] left, 
                                       int[] right) {
    int i1 = 0;   // index into left array
    int i2 = 0;   // index into right array

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        compCount++;
        if (i2 >= right.length ||
           (i1 < left.length && left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
            result[i] = left[i1];    // take from left
            i1++;
            //swapCount++;
        } else {
            result[i] = right[i2];   // take from right
            i2++;
            //swapCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("merge sort " + compCount + " " + swapCount);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with an interactive debugger? If so can you see where it is not returning the expected result?

Comment: Everything works correctly, I'm just curious if this is the correct way to count the compare and swaps for a merge sort.